# How can i add a behavior of long presion of shortcut?

Tags: wpf, xaml, input, data-binding, gesture

My inputbinding is something like that :

```
 <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding NewCommand}"/>
```

I want to add a delay for this command.
For example, i would to hold down my two buttons 3sec and after the command run.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in ViewModel using Thread.Sleep

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand NewCommand { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        NewCommand = new RelayCommand(Command);
    }

    private void Command(object parameter)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
    }
}
```